# Run a custom script more than 20 times in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need a way of running a custom script more than 20 times in my spreadsheet.  I'm creating a class assessment spreadsheet that will be used as a master across my school, and it needs to retrieve the names of the students in each class.  Each student's name is a sheet name in the spreadsheet.  These are retrieved by numerical reference to the sheet they are on (i.e. =getsheetname(2) returns 'John Smith' for the spreadsheet for class 2B, but 'Sarah Jones' for class 5A's spreadsheet).

However I keep getting:

> error: too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line20, file "Code")

This is the code:

```
function getSheetName1(index) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets(); 
  var allSheetNames = new Array(); 
  var SheetNumber = allSheets.length; 
  if (arguments.length == 0) { 
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  } else { 
    for (var i = 0; i < SheetNumber; i++) { 
      allSheetNames[i] = allSheets[i].getName();
    } 
    if (index == 0) { 
      return allSheetNames; 
    } else { 
      return allSheetNames[index-1];
    }
  }
}
```

I understand this is because I can only run the custom script 20 times, but there are 30 students in each class.  Is there a way to circumvent this? I have only a basic understanding of code so your patience would be appreciated!

Comment: The error message indicates that the error originates from line `20` in your code! If you want us to have a look, then please share the code. Welcome to Web Applications !!

Comment: Thanks @Jacob, please find below:                         function getSheetName1(index) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var allSheetNames = new Array();
  var SheetNumber = allSheets.length;
  

  if (arguments.length == 0) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
 } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < SheetNumber; i++)
    {
     allSheetNames[i] = allSheets[i].getName();
    }
    if (index == 0) {
     return allSheetNames;
    }
    else {
     return allSheetNames[index-1];
    }
   } 

}

Comment: That's a complete mess sorry, I can share the link to the google spreadsheet if that's more helpful?

Comment: If the info can bare the daylight, then yes, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of days of looking at your code and I think I may have a solution, but it's a little bit of a kludge.

You can create a function that returns a 2D array which will fill the cells below and to the right of the original cell. So I would try something like this: ([sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Au17ekRhm0HjdHR5VmFGRGlNZTNCdmxkWEtaaFRHeEE&usp=sharing))

```
= getSheetNames(2)
```

where your student sheets are after the second sheet, and use this custom function:

```
function getSheetNames(after) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    after = 0;
  }
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var allSheetNames = [];
  var sheetCount = allSheets.length;

  for (var i = after; i < sheetCount; i++) {
    //as you're putting them all in one row, you don't use array wrappers
    allSheetNames.push(allSheets[i].getName());
    //because it's merged need to add extra cell
    allSheetNames.push('');
  }
  return allSheetNames;
}
```

Edit - as you are using one row and inserting into merged cells - I have made some changes

Comment: Many thanks @Tom Horwood, apologies for late response, have been out of the country.  I will try this code and get back to you. Please click here if you'd like to see the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArhkOMgC7ss5dGEwbUwzN0htNzBpamJta2JjZXhEOXc&usp=sharing

Comment: Also thanks to @Jacob, would only let me put one person in at a time!